# Possibilities to place $k$ persons on a round table with $n$ seats such that there is at least one free seat between each $2$ persons

Tags: combinatorics

How many possibilities are there to place $k$ persons on a round table with $n$ seats in such a way that there is at least one free seat between each $2$ persons?
The seats are not distinguishable, meaning that rotationally symmetric arrangements are equal.

Does it make sense to say $\frac{k+(n-2k)!}{n-2k} =$ (Persons + Free Seats)! / Free Seats because they are not distinguishable?

I think it's wrong.

Comment: A hint is to think of an orientation and then think of a linear order where there is someone in the leftmost chair and the rightmost is empty (as we must have a free chair between any two people and having both ends full is like having neighbors around the circular table). Then consider a person sitting as taking up two chairs, theirs and the one to the right. **This would be my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's choose where there are people. To do that, we consider the $k$ people as "slots" for people. Between them are "slots" for empty chairs. We want to decide where to place empty chairs. Because there are $k$ people, there are $k$ slots. Place one empty seat in each slot. Now, we want to choose how many additional chairs to place in each slot. This is a stars and bars problem. There are $k$ slots and $n-2k$ remaining seats that need to be placed. So, there are:

$$\dbinom{n-2k+k-1}{k-1} = \dbinom{n-k-1}{k-1}$$

ways to place the remaining seats.

Next, arrange the people. There are $(k-1)!$ circle-arrangements for the people to their chosen slots.

Total:

$$\dbinom{n-k-1}{k-1}(k-1)! = \dfrac{(n-k-1)!}{(n-2k)!}$$